# How to evaluate df(x)/dx at x=c rather than df(c)/dx when defining a reusable macro?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, pstricks-add

The following macros define `\f[#1]` and its derivative `\fp[#1]`.

```
\def\f[#1]{((#1)*(#1-1)*(#1-2)*(#1-3)*(#1-5)/10+1.5)}
\edef\fp[#1]{Derive(1,\f[#1])}
```

## Question

I want to define a reusable macro `\g{<contant>}{<variable-x>}`. Unfortunately,
`\fp[0.8]` that should mean the value of `df/dx` at `x=0.8` always evaluates to `df[0.8]/dx` that always equals to zero?

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\def\f[#1]{(#1)*(#1-1)*(#1-2)*(#1-3)*(#1-5)/10+1.5}
\def\fDerivation#1#2{ 
    /x #1 def /F (Derive(1,#2)) tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end cvx def 
    x F}
\def\g#1#2{(\fDerivation{#1}{\f[#2]})*(#2-#1)+\f[#1]} % y = f'(x0)*(x-x0) +f(x0)
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](0,-2)(3,3)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{2}{\f[x]}
\psplot{0}{2}{\g{2}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f[x]}{\g{2}{x}}{5}{A} % <------- this is important part!
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is with help of `polexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{polexpr}

\poldef f(x):=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)/10+1.5;
\PolReduceCoeffs{f}
\PolDiff{f}{f'}
\PolReduceCoeffs{f'}

\let\PolToExprOneTerm\PolToExprOneTermStyleB
\edef\f{\PolToExpr{f}}% uses x (\PolToExprVar default)
% \show\f % style "B" puts denominators on the right
% > \f=macro:
% ->x^5/10-11*x^4/10+41*x^3/10-61*x^2/10+3*x+3/2.

% first try:

% \def\g#1#2{\PolEval{f'}\At{#1}*(#2-#1) + 
%            \PolEval{f}\At{#1}} % y = f'(x0)*(x-x0) +f(x0)

% but this is bad:
% \edef\test{\g{.8}{x}}
% \show\test 
% uses xintfrac internal notation, which are no good for pstricks

% malax things to get output syntax understandable by external world
% (I should make it easier)
\newcommand\g[2]{\PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\PolEval{f'}\At{#1}}}*(#2-#1) + 
                 \PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\PolEval{f}\At{#1}}}} % y = f'(x0)*(x-x0) +f(x0)

% \edef\test{\g{.8}{x}}
% \show\test % -0.936*(x-.8) + 1.677408

% \xintverbosetrue
% \poldef k(x) := f(x) - (\g{1.4}{x}); don't forget parentheses here!
% \typeout{\PolToExpr{k}, \PolEval{k}\At{1.4}}% ok, evaluates to zero
% \PolToSturm{k}{k}
% \PolSturmIsolateZeros{k}
% \PolEnsureIntervalLengths{k}{-10}
% Package xintexpr Info: (on line 40)
%     Variable "kL_3" globally defined with value 32629939266/1[-10].

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](0,-2)(6,4)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{5.18}{\f}

\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{6}{\g{2}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{2}{x}}{5}{A} % <------- this is important part!

% This is ok
\psplot[linecolor=black]{0}{6}{\g{1.5}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.5}{x}}{5}{C}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.5}{x}}{3}{D}

\psplot[linecolor=black]{0}{6}{\g{1.4}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.4}{x}}{5}{C1}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.4}{x}}{3.2629939266}{D1}%  we have to input almost exact abscissa !!

\psplot[linecolor=black]{0}{6}{\g{1.3}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.3}{x}}{5}{C2}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.3}{x}}{3}{D2}

\psplot[linecolor=black]{0}{6}{\g{1.2}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.2}{x}}{5}{C3}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.2}{x}}{3.7}{D3}% we have to input very close abscissa !!

\psplot[linecolor=black]{0}{6}{\g{1.1}{x}}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.1}{x}}{5}{C4}
\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{1.1}{x}}{3.9}{D4}% we have to input very close abscissa !!


% \psplot[linecolor=green]{0}{6}{\g{0.8}{x}}
% \pstInterFF{\f}{\g{0.8}{x}}{5}{E}% no
% (I get errors on ghostscript side)

%\psplot[linecolor=cyan]{0}{6}{\g{3}{x}}
%\pstInterFF{\f}{\g{3}{x}}{4.8}{B}% fails to find it!

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Remark: I had some issues with ghostscript for example

```
Running `Ps2pdf' on `testpstricks' with ``ps2pdf testpstricks.ps''
DEBUG: FC_WEIGHT didn't match
```

But the worse is apparently when `\pstInterFF` fails to find a point. But I am no good at understanding Ghostscript.

My experience here is that `\pstInterFF` is unpredictably sometimes unable to find nearby root. For D1 I gave it my best visual estimate with 1 decimal precision but it failed to find it, so I computed it via `polexpr` with 10 decimals precision first.

About using `polexpr` it is not always immediate to let it speak with external worlds due to `xintfrac` internal notation `A/B[N]` for fractions. `\PolToExpr` does not use it on output, but `\PolEval` does use it on output, so I had to wrap this output into some additional routines.

[image]

---

---

Still with the help of [`polexpr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polexpr) I have determined all points where the tangent meets the curve at another point again tangentially.

It turns out they are exactly 3 pairs of such points, thus a total of 6 points, and that 2 among the six are very very close to each other. It is impossible to distinguish visually.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{polexpr}

\poldef f(x):=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)/10+1.5;
\PolReduceCoeffs{f}
\PolDiff{f}{f'}
\PolDiff{f'}{f''}
\PolDiff{f''}{f3}
\PolDiff{f3}{f4}
\PolDiff{f4}{f5}


% \xintverbosetrue

\poldef Delta(x) := subs(subs(subs(subs(
                         18*a*b*c*d-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4a*c^3-27a^2d^2,
                   d=f''(x)/2), c=f3(x)/6), b=f4(x)/24), a=f5(x)/120);

\PolReduceCoeffs{Delta}% coefficients are not automatically reduced to
% smallest terms, let's do it. (but any way the Sturm chain polynomials 
% automatically are made integer coefficients with no common factor)

\PolToSturm{Delta}{DeltaSturm}
\PolSturmIsolateZeros{DeltaSturm}
\PolEnsureIntervalLengths{DeltaSturm}{-20}

\let\PolToExprOneTerm\PolToExprOneTermStyleB
\newcommand\f{}
\edef\f{\PolToExpr{f}}% uses x (\PolToExprVar default)
% \show\f % style "B" puts denominators on the right
% > \f=macro:
% ->x^5/10-11*x^4/10+41*x^3/10-61*x^2/10+3*x+3/2.

% malax things to get output syntax understandable by external world
% (I should make it easier)
\newcommand\g[2]{\PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\PolEval{f'}\At{#1}}}*(#2-#1) + 
                 \PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\PolEval{f}\At{#1}}}} % y = f'(x0)*(x-x0) +f(x0)

% \edef\test{\g{.8}{x}}
% \show\test % -0.936*(x-.8) + 1.677408

\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
\PolPrintIntervals{DeltaSturm} % (or use \xintverbosetrue and check in log)

% 1 0.38196601125010515179...
% 2 0.69722436226800535344...
% 3 0.89706136340735988338...
% 4 2.61803398874989484820...
% 5 4.30277563773199464655...
% 6 4.30293863659264011661...
\end{preview}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](0,-2)(6,4)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{5.18}{\f}

% 3 0.89706136340735988338...
\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{6}{\g{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{DeltaSturm}{3}}{x}}

\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](0,-2)(6,4)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{5.18}{\f}

% 2 0.69722436226800535344...
\psplot[linecolor=green]{0}{6}{\g{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{DeltaSturm}{2}}{x}}

\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](0,-2)(6,4)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{5.18}{\f}

% 1 0.38196601125010515179...
\psplot[linecolor=magenta]{0}{6}{\g{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{DeltaSturm}{1}}{x}}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first two are NOT the same (the red and the green tangents are not the same straight line). Hopefully, I did not make some stupid mistake in setting up the formula for computing the discriminant `Delta(x_0)` of the degree 3 polynomial `(f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x-x_0))/(x-x_0)^2` which vanishes exactly when the tangent at `x_0` has another tangential point. It seems to work visually, and the near coincidence of two points is amusing.

Of course with arbitrary precision software such as `polexpr` we can not be fooled!

---

---

*update* à propos the computation of the degree 6 polynomial giving the points with double-tangents, the nested `subs(subs(...` were there for a slight optimization which evaluates the `a, b, c, d` only once, but here `a, b, c, d` are not replaced by numerical values but "polynomials" so the gain from the nested `subs` is about nil (when one knows how `\poldef` works internally). Anyway, it is clearer to first define the discriminant of degree-3 polynomials as an `xintexpr` function and then use it in `\poldef` syntax.

```
% polexpr allows only to define one-variable polynomials (currently)
% but we only need this as a "function" (i.e. a complicated nested
% usages of xintfrac macros):

\xintdeffunc Delta3(a, b, c, d) := 18a*b*c*d-27a^2d^2-4a*c^3-4b^3d+b^2c^2;

% and we can then use this "function" with arguments being
% _polynomials_, to create a genuine _polynomial_

\poldef Delta(x) := Delta3(f5(x)/120, f4(x)/24, f3(x)/6, f''(x)/2);

% or, and we could as well have written 18*(f5(x)/120)*(f4(x)/24)*....
% but this would be barely readable, so we use the nested "subs" for clarity
% \poldef Delta(x) := subs(subs(subs(subs(
%                          18a*b*c*d-27a^2d^2-4a*c^3-4b^3d+b^2c^2;
%                    d=f''(x)/2), c=f3(x)/6), b=f4(x)/24), a=f5(x)/120);
\PolReduceCoeffs{Delta}

% \let\PolToExprOneTerm\PolToExprOneTermStyleB
% \typeout{HERE IT IS: \PolToExpr{Delta}}
```

The degree 6 polynomial is exactly this:

```
-x^6/50+33*x^5/125-3223*x^4/2500+1796*x^3/625-7457*x^2/2500+1741*x/1250-579/2500
```

(it is not hard to do all these computations by hand, btw)

Comment: side remark `x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)/10+1.5` uses only division by 10, so all coefficients are decimal number, and when evaluation at a decimal number we still have decimal number. The `\PolDecToString` business will convert say `7/100` into `0.07` which PSTricks accepts, but if the original was `100/7` it would remain `100/7`. I just tested `\poldef f(x):=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)/7+1.5;` and it seems to work perfectly fine. Thus PSTricks accepts fraction, I could also have used `\xintIrr{\PolEval{f}\At{#1}}` in place of `\PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\PolEval{f}\At{#1}}}` then.

Comment: attention that `18*a*b*c*d` can not be written `18abcd` because `abcd` is a legitimate variable name and `xint` does not trace back its steps when discovering `abcd` has no assigned value. Thus `*` is mandatory (`18a*b*c*d` of course ok)

Comment: I understand better the "closeness": look at the picture with D's and C's, when moving downwards we reach a double-tangent, then still moving downwards, the tangent has no real point of intersection (x=0.8 for example), then the tangent starts moving back up when x decreases towards 0.69722.. and there it touches again on the right, near but not exactly where it last touched the curve... (I have not checked if the new contact is on left or right of the ones from the D's and C's series...)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\f[#1]{(#1)*(#1-1)*(#1-2)*(#1-3)*(#1-5)/10+1.5}
\def\fDerivation#1#2{ 
    /x #1 def /F (Derive(1,#2)) tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end cvx def 
    x F}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-2)(3,3)
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{0}{2}{\f[x]}
\psplot[algebraic]{0}{2}{Derive(1,\f[x])}
\psdot[dotscale=2,linecolor=red](!\fDerivation{0.8}{\f[x]})
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-calculate,pstricks-add}
\def\f[#1]{(#1)*(#1-1)*(#1-2)*(#1-3)*(#1-5)/10+1.5}
\def\fDerivation#1#2{ 
    /x #1 def /F (Derive(1,#2)) tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end cvx def 
    x F /M exch def pop}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-2)(3,3)
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{0}{2}{\f[x]}
    \psplot[algebraic]{0}{2}{Derive(1,\f[x])}
    \psplot[linecolor=red,algebraic]{0}{3}[\fDerivation{0.8}{\f[x]}]{%
        M*(x-0.8)+\pscalculate{\f[0.8]}}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]